# How can i get the union of two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables.

Table A : with ID column and values
1
2
3

Table B: with ID column and values
2
3
4

I want a result set in the below form

[image: ID PresentInA PresentInB]

Answer (score 1):

You can find your solution using below query ,if id is a PK.

```
select id,
(case when id in (select * from tableA)  then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as PRESENTINA,
(case when id not in (select * from tableB)  then 'NO' else 'YES' end) as PRESENTINB
from tableA
union
select id,
(case when id in (select * from tableA)  then 'YES' else 'NO' end) As PRESENTINA,
(case when id not in (select * from tableB)  then 'NO' else 'YES' end) as PRESENTINB 
from tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is unique, you can use a `full join`:

```
select id,
       (case when a.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PresentInA,
       (case when b.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PresentInB
from a full join
     b
     using (id);
```

If `id` is not unique, you *could* add aggregation to the above.  Instead, I think I would use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select id, max(PresentInA) as PresentInA, max(PresentInB) as PresentInB
from ((select distinct a.id, 'Yes' as PresentInA, 'No' as PresentInB
       from a
      ) union all
      (select distinct b.id, 'No' as PresentInA, 'Yes' as PresentInB
       from b
      ) 
     ) ab
group by id;
```

This prevents excessive processing if one `id` is duplicated many times in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

using union and left join you try like below

```
with cte
as(
select 1 as id
union all
select 2
union all
select 3 )
,
cte2 AS
(
select 2 as id
union all
select 3 
union all
select 4 )
, cte3 as (
select id from cte
union 
select id from cte2
) select cte3.id, case when cte.id is null then 'NO' else 'Yes' end as prestnInA,
case when cte2.id is null then 'NO' else 'Yes' end as prestnInB
    from cte3
  left join cte on cte3.id=cte.id
  left join cte2 on cte3.id=cte2.id
```

output

```
id  prestnInA   prestnInB
1   Yes         NO
2   Yes         Yes
3   Yes         Yes
4   NO          Yes
```

[DEMO LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cfdedd06de1c99d531b6fa62cdf9fa7d)